# MSDTC on server '' is unavailable. sql server link server error when call stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, wcf, stored-procedures, msdtc

I have 3 servers with these names `ServiceServer`, `DatabaseServer` and `WarehouseServer`.

I have a WCF service on `ServiceServer` that calls a stored procedure in `DatabaseServer`.

```
public async void UpdateStatus(NajaResult najaresult, string userid, string IsWorn, string FuelSystem, string ValidTest, string SymfaServiceStatus, string NajaServiceStatus)
{
    string _FuelSystem = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(FuelSystem)) ? "2" : FuelSystem;
    _ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("EXEC [dbo].[UpdateInquiryStatus] @userid='" + userid + "', @IsWorn='" + IsWorn + "',@FuelSystem='" + _FuelSystem + "',@ValidTest='" + ValidTest + "',@SymfaServiceStatus='" + SymfaServiceStatus + "',@NajaServiceStatus='" + NajaServiceStatus + "' ,"
+ "@Chassis='" + najaresult.Chassis + "',@CarColor=N'" + najaresult.CarColor + "',@MotorNum='" + najaresult.MotorNum + "' ,@Vin='" + najaresult.VinNo + "', @SystemType=N'" + najaresult.SystemType + "',@CarTipe=N'" + najaresult.CarTip + "',@FuelType='" + najaresult.FuelType + "',@Model='" + najaresult.CarModel + "'" + ",@CarType=N'" + najaresult.CarType + "'");
}
```

Here is my stored procedure `UpdateInquiryStatus` that is located in `DatabaseServer`:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateInquiryStatus]
    @userid nvarchar(max),
    @IsWorn nvarchar(max),
    @FuelSystem nvarchar(max),
    @ValidTest nvarchar(max),
    @SymfaServiceStatus nvarchar(max),
    @NajaServiceStatus nvarchar(max),
    @Vin nvarchar(max),
    @SystemType nvarchar(max),
    @CarTipe nvarchar(max),
    @FuelType nvarchar(max),
    @Model nvarchar(max),
    @Chassis nvarchar(max),
    @CarColor nvarchar(max),
    @MotorNum nvarchar(max),
    @CarType nvarchar(max)
AS   
    INSERT INTO [PRISYMFA22a1\MASSYMSQLSERVER].[DB].[dbo].AutomotiveTemps 
           (id, isworn, validtest, CarColor, CarTipe, CarType, Chassis, 
            FuelSystem, FuelType, Model, MotorNum, SubmitDatetime, 
            SystemType, UserId, VIN)
    VALUES (NEWID(), @IsWorn, @ValidTest, @CarColor, @CarTipe, @CarType, @Chassis,
            @FuelSystem, @FuelType, @Model, @MotorNum, GETDATE(),
            @SystemType, @userid, @Vin)
```

As a note I created a link server between `DatabaseServer` and `WarehouseServer`.

As you can, see my procedure inserts a record into `WarehouseServer` but I get this error :

> MSDTC on server 'DatabaseServer' is unavailable.

but my msdtc is running and all firewalls are disabled. I opened all inbound and outbound remote in component service too. But same error is being returned

Comment: You should **really** use the **most appropriate** datatype - and not just use `nvarchar(max)` for everything out of lazyness. Things like `@IsWorn` sounds like a boolean flag - use `BIT`. And `Id` typically is a numeric value - use an appropriate *numeric* datatype like `INT` or `DECIMAL` etc. and even most string types most likely really don't have to be capable of holding **UP to 2 GB** of string data - use **appropriate** lengths for your parameters!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Component Services on DatabaseServer and navigate down to Local DTC, right-click and select properties.

On the Security tab make sure Network DTC Access is checked and Allow Remote Clients.

Check Allow Inbound (and maybe Outbound) under Transaction Manager Communication and you may need to alter the Authentication depending on which versions of Windows you are running on both DatabaseServer and ServiceServer.

Comment: Any idea when this is needed? I have a single sql server instance and a reporting tool that calls it. With MSDTC off, I sometimes I get this error from it and sometimes I don't, while the executing code is identical in both cases.